# How to Choose a Microsoft SQL Server Edition 2012 as a Developer?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I hope this question isn't too obtuse; however, I couldn't find anything specific. I'm a web-developer and I have an MSDN Subscription that gives me access to any SQL server edition I want. As a developer, I would like to know what I should choose to install on a dev machine based on this criteria (which other developers may relate to):

1. I need access to all the tools for SQL and T-SQL programming (I think all editions come with this?)
2. I want it to be efficient--I don't want it to take up too much ram\cpu processing time. My queries will not be very heavy so I'd rather trade off longer queries than to have the server taking up valuable resources.
3. I am programming for an enterprise sql version hosted somwhere else, but I don't need more than 1 Gigs of space, 1 CPU core support,
4. I never really worked with reporting tools, but would as a developer (Aka, non-DBA) would I ever need them on a dev machine?
5. Best integration with VS2013

I know that the SQL Server Developer edition is basically Enterprise, but without the liscence to use it for non-dev purposes. Based on the above criteria is there any sense for me to install it? Or should I choose SQL Express with Advanced Services? Perhaps Web?

Thanks for all your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All editions come with all the tools (unless you get into the BI side of things, then I think Express won't come with all of those tools).
2. In general, the edition won't make your local development environment any different in terms of resource usage. There are a few things that Enterprise / Developer have (like online index rebuild, certain optimizations etc.) that can make some operations more efficient, but these are highly unlikely to impact your day-to-day work or really change the number of resources SQL Server uses (these are very easy to cap through configuration anyway, e.g. if you don't want SQL Server to use more than x GB of memory, you can set that).
3. If you don't need more than 1 GB / 1 CPU in the ultimate deployment, you should probably develop on Express. This will prevent you from using Enterprise features inadvertently (which can happen if you use Developer). The down-side is that if you later *do* need features that aren't in Express (say you have another project where you will be deploying to Enterprise), you'll need to add an instance (with or without removing the old one). Given that you have access to MSDN, maybe the best solution is to install two instances - one Express, and one Developer, and then you can target the edition you want by using the appropriate instance locally.
4. I think that Express with Advanced Services come with these things, but I'm not an SSRS guy, so I'm not sure.
5. No single aspect of integration with Visual Studio should be edition-dependent.

Also, Web is not an edition that is suitable for your workstation - try to find a license somewhere. This edition is exclusively for web hosts and resellers who offer SQL Server as part of their hosted offerings.

Comment: 3. Oh sorry I should say that I don't need the SQL Server on my dev machine to be more than that. The deployment database is a full enterprise one running multi-core and much larger. I just didn't want the dev DB to take up too much resource. Number 2 answered that for me though! THank you. 

Based on your answer, I think I will choose the Developer edition and try to set a cap to how much memory it can use. 

**Awesome answer.**